# Symfony 2 - Trying to get the properties from another method in the same class

Tags: php, oop, symfony, doctrine, dql

As you can see in the code below, I am attempting to make a sub-navigation. I want to make it from scratch, rather than use a bundle because I'm using this as a learning exercise. I've reached a point where I *think* I've just about cracked it. All I need now is to access the results of the navAction() db query inside subNavAction().

I've managed to get as far as 'echo self::navAction($sector);' which DOES echo out the full navigation again but I can't seem to access individual items in the query. What I actually need to do is to loop through the results of navAction() and get the results for all items with children.

I am really new to OOPHP (although I know procedural quite well) and Symfony/Doctrine so the more comprehensive and answer you can give me, the better.

```
//Render Navigation
public function navAction($sector)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
       "SELECT DISTINCT p.pageName, p.pageParent
        FROM styleGuideBundle:pages p 
        WHERE  p.pageSector LIKE :sector 
        AND p.pageType = 2"
    );
    $query->setParameter(':sector', '%'.$sector.'%');
    $navItems = $query->getResult();
    if (!$navItems) throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find any pages under this category');
    return $this->render(
        'styleGuideBundle:Partial:peNav.html.twig',
        array(
            'navItems' => $navItems,
            'sector' => $sector
        )
    );
}

//Render SubNavigation
public function subnavAction($sector)
{
    echo self::navAction($sector); // This line is where I got stuck.
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
       "SELECT DISTINCT p.pageName, p.pageParent
        FROM styleGuideBundle:pages p 
        WHERE  p.pageSector LIKE :sector 
        AND p.pageType = 2"
    );
    $query->setParameter(':sector', '%'.$sector.'%');
    $navItems = $query->getResult();
    if (!$navItems) throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find any pages under this category');
    return $this->render(
        'styleGuideBundle:Partial:peNav.html.twig',
        array(
            'navItems' => $navItems,
            'sector' => $sector
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best solution,but you can create an object variable $this->navItems;

```
PageController extends Controller {

      public $navItems = null; 

    //Render Navigation
        public function navAction($sector)
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $query = $em->createQuery(
               "SELECT DISTINCT p.pageName, p.pageParent
                FROM styleGuideBundle:pages p 
                WHERE  p.pageSector LIKE :sector 
                AND p.pageType = 2"
            );
            $query->setParameter(':sector', '%'.$sector.'%');
            $this->navItems = $query->getResult();

            if (!$this->navItems) throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find any pages under this category');
            return $this->render(
                'styleGuideBundle:Partial:peNav.html.twig',
                array(
                    'navItems' => $this->navItems,
                    'sector' => $sector
                )
            );
        }


        //Render SubNavigation
        public function subnavAction($sector)
        {
            $this->navAction($sector);
            var_dump($this->navItems);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $query = $em->createQuery(
               "SELECT DISTINCT p.pageName, p.pageParent
                FROM styleGuideBundle:pages p 
                WHERE  p.pageSector LIKE :sector 
                AND p.pageType = 2"
            );
            $query->setParameter(':sector', '%'.$sector.'%');
            $navItems = $query->getResult();
            if (!$navItems) throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find any pages under this category');
            return $this->render(
                'styleGuideBundle:Partial:peNav.html.twig',
                array(
                    'navItems' => $navItems,
                    'sector' => $sector
                )
            );
}
```

Comment: See that's how I thought I should have done it after a google search but it results in the following error:

Notice: Undefined property: StyleGuideBundle\Controller\PageController::$navItems in /Volumes/Projects/Style Guide/site/Guidelines/src/StyleGuideBundle/Controller/PageController.php line 104

Comment: Just create it in you controller: --> class PageController extends Controller { $this->navItems = null; ...

Comment: It didn't like that either:

"FatalErrorException: Parse: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)"

Comment: I tried it like this  "public $navItems = null;" and the error changed to this:

"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

Comment: Sorry yes, like this : public $navItems = null; and now you can get $this->navItems variable in your controller. try to print_r($this->navItems);

Comment: you need to use  $this->navAction($sector) instead of  self::navAction($sector);

Comment: Ok so no error now but no output either. Tried this:

    echo 'b1';
    $this->navAction($sector);
    print_r($this->navItems);
    echo 'b2';

and got this: 'b1b2'

Comment: This is in Symfony2. That doesn't make a difference does it?

Comment: $this->navItems = $query->getResult(); this variable should contain your query results.,after that  you can view it like var_dump($this->navItems);

Comment: Sorry. Really not having much luck here. '$this->navItems = $query->getResult();' gives me this error: "Error: Call to a member function getResult() on a non-object"

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please show me what's the output of var_dump();

Comment: just comes out as 'Null'

Comment: Try to check your query,cos you just saved your result to the class variable and you can access it any time you want. if query has returned null,it means (there is no matching) http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: hmmm... I know the query works as if I access the 'navAction()' method. It gives me the top level of the navigation. So I'm not sure what could be wrong with the query. It just doesn't seem to want to be retrievable by anything other than the view.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually returning it to be accessible to the class as it seems to be sending it straight to the view:

return $this->render(
            'styleGuideBundle:Partial:peNav.html.twig',
            array(
                'navItems' => $navItems,
                'sector' => $sector
            )
        );

Comment: Just done a little test and this variable:  public $navItems = null; is never being populated. If I change it to  public $navItems = 1; then var_dump() outputs int(1).

Comment: Not going to pursue this question anymore. I'm going to combine it into one controller if possible. I've got another question here which is related to what I'm doing now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640018/symfony-2-create-sub-navigation